# Are there an endless number of imaginary square roots for negative one?

Tags: radicals, octonions

When i learned about imaginary numbers, I learned that i represents the square root of negative one, as does i's counterpart below zero, "-i."

But then I learned the same is true of the quaternion imginary units j and k.

And then I leaned the same is true of the octonion imaginary units e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6 and e7.

I couold not find any information on the specifics of the sedonion imaginary units but I assume the same is true of all of them.

And then I learned about the Cayley Dickson Construction which extends these patterns of numbers based on imaginary units endlessly.

Am I wrong in assuming there are therefore an endless number of imaginary square roots to negative one and that this is proven by the Cayley Dickson Construction, but that there are just two real square roots (+1, -1) to positive one?

I'm just an interested math novice so apologies if I've made any errors and please do your best wherever possible to answer as if speaking to a ten year old.  Thank you.  :-)

Comment: Already the quaternions have uncountably many square roots of $-1$.

Comment: In the Cayley-Dickson construction, we start with $\Bbb R$ and keep doubling the dimension, and this comment assumes hereafter that's done by adding square roots of $-1$, not $1$ or $0$. In the $2^n$-ions, the square roots of $-1$ are then the numbers with zero real part whose imaginary parts are a unit vector in $\Bbb R^{2^n-1}$. This generalizes @QiaochuYuan's point about the case $n=2$.

Comment: @J.G. Sorry I'm not yet at the level to understand all of your comment. Are you saying that after the sedonions, the Cayley-Dickson doubling of the pattern does not mean more units are added which are square roots of negative one but that units are instead added which are square roots of one or zero?

Comment: No, not at all. You can add any one of three square-root types at each doubling step, but if you only ever add square roots of $-1$ the solutions of $z^2=-1$ behave as I described.

Comment: In usual (4-dimensional) tessarines, you have $4$ squre roots of $-1$: $i,-i,ij,-ij$. Each $n$-degree polynomial has $n^2$ roots in tessarines.

Answer (score 7):

It only makes sense to ask how many roots a given number has within a specific number system. In particular, here is the situation with respect to $1$ and $-1$:

- In $\mathbb{R}$, $1$ has two square roots and $-1$ has no square roots.
- In $\mathbb{C}$, both $1$ and $-1$ have two square roots.
- In $\mathbb{H}$ (= the quaternions), every negative real number has **infinitely many** square roots! For example, not only are $i,j,k$ each square roots of $-1$ in $\mathbb{H}$, but so is ${1\over\sqrt{2}}(i+j)$ since $$(i+j)^2=i^2+ij+ji+j^2=-2.$$ (So there's no need to go any further with the Cayley-Dickson process.)

The term "imaginary" usually refers specifically to $\mathbb{C}$, so I would not say your claim is justified as phrased. Rather, I would say that what the Cayley-Dickson process demonstrates is that once we loosen our sense of what "number" is to allow general "reasonably nice rings," there is nothing preventing everything from having lots of square roots.

Comment: Ahh, okay thank you.  This is very helpful.  I thought "j" and "k" could be referred to as "imaginary numbers" but I guess they are really "quaternion units"?  I also found this link with a diagram https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-square-root-of-1-in-a-quaternionic-number-system which helps me build a bit of intuition around square roots of negative one in the quaternions.  I'm still struggling with why positive one could have more than two square roots there, but as I said I'm a math novice and I am also still very new to learning about these systems and don't understand them well yet.

Comment: Well, if the "reasonably nice ring" is so nice to embed into a (commutative) field, then no element can have more than two square roots. In fact, "generally" (i.e. excluding characteristic $2$ and the zero element), elements of such rings have either exactly two square roots or none at all. (You know this, but I point it out for the OP.)

Comment: EDIT to my comment above:  I think maybe you meant the negative reals have infinitely many square roots in the quaternions?  I found this about quaternions including the positive real numbers:   "If a quaternion is not a negative real number, then the story is much more familiar: the equation x² = y has one solution if y = 0 and two solutions otherwise." https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2021/01/06/quaternion-square-roots/

Comment: @HRW Whoops, good catch. Fixed!

Comment: @NoahSchweber great!  Thanks.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

It may help to re-imagine what "$i$" is: it is a number - in whatever context you are working in - that satisfies $$i^2 = -1.$$ Or equivalently, it is a root of the equation $$x^2 +1 = 0.$$
Note that this definition doesn't imply existence or uniqueness of $i$! As Noah mentions, over the $\mathbb{R}$, no such solution exists (the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ is in fact irreducible). Over $\mathbb{C}$ there are two solutions; by convention we call one of them $i$ and the other $-i$. In other number systems, such as quaternions, there are more solutions.

However if we are working over a field (an especially nice ring, where multiplication is commutative and nonzero elements have multiplicative inverses), we can in fact say there are *at most 2 solutions* to the polynomial $x^2 + 1$. So to answer your question: if we are interested in "imaginary square roots" contained in a field, then there can be at most two. $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are fields, while $\mathbb{H}$ is not.

This is useful because it extends to things like finite fields. In the finite field of 5 elements, $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, we have $2^2 = 4 \equiv -1 \pmod{5}$, so perhaps 2 deserves to be called $i$ in this setting? This is not standard notation (we would instead call -1 a quadratic residue modulo 5), but illustrates that in other number systems we can find things that satisfy similar properties. On the other hand, the finite field with 3 elements, $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, -1 is not a quadratic residue, i.e. there is no element deserving of the name $i$.

One final point: in some sense, this approach doesn't allow us to *distinguish* between $+i$ and $-i$. After all, both are solutions to $x^2 + 1$. In fact, swapping these labels is precisely complex conjugation, which extends to an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ sending $$a + bi \mapsto a - bi.$$
This isn't usually an issue, but to avoid confusion sometimes you'll see people say "fix an algebraic closure of the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$." This makes sure we have all agreed on which is $+i$ and which is $-i$ up front (and all the other roots of all the other polynomials!).

Answer (score 0):

Besides Cayley-Dickson Construction, you can have tessarines of $2^n$ dimension. In each such system there is one real unit, $1$, $2^n/2-1$ hypernbolic units ($2^n-2$ non-real roots of 1), and $2^n/2$ imaginary units ($2^n$ non-real roots of $1$). Each such system, regardless of dimension is associative and commutative.

Alternatively, you can consider $\mathbb{C}^n$ with Hadamard (element-wise) product. It is $2n$-dimensional and has $2^n$ roots of $-1$. Each such system is also commutative and associative.

For instance, in $9$-dimensional case, one root of $-1$ is $(i,-i,-i,i,i,i-i,-i,i)$:

$(i,-i,-i,i,i,i-i,-i,i)^2=(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)=-1$